# Sobolev spaces documentation

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

Can someone indicate some documentation on this subject? (thoroughly explained with a presentation of its applications - mostly interested in the FEM. However just a good presentation of the Sobolev spaces will suffice)

Comment: I do not know how useful this book might be to beginners as I am just using it to look up estimates and for reference, but you might try Adams: "Sobolev spaces".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn the basics of Sobolev Spaces, you can consult [Brezis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134) or [Evans](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) books. If you need a more detailed knowledge of the subject then, you can consult [Adams](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120441438) book, which as cited above by @dinosaur, or you can take a look on [Leoni's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686) book.

I apologizem but with respect to FEM I can't say nothing.